# Bottom floating div (like in facebook messages)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, css-float

I'm looking for some type of css (maybe jquery) solutions where the div would always stay at the bottom of the sreen - like this is done on facebook -> view messages -> individual message conversation. The "Reply" box always stays at the bottom and when you scroll to the top to see previous messages the reply box also moves up.

thanks

Comment: if you want an item to be fixed on the page, give it the css property, position: fixed

Comment: Do you have specific browser requirements? If you need IE6 support `position:fixed`, on its own, will not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML:

```
    <body>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
}
```

jQuery to scroll to bottom on load:

```
$(function(){
    $("body").animate({scrollTop: $(this).height()}, 1000); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/CCpJg/5/

Comment: the problem with this is that when i scroll to the top the "footer" div should be always on TOP of the page content. So the page starts off being "at the bottom", and I should be able to scroll to top.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using CSS fixed positioning?

```
#bottomDiv
{
   position: fixed;
   right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Just trying to imitate Facebook, nothing more :D

Answer (score 0):

you can use the css property

```
div.theItem {
   position: fixed;

}
```